# Can I use the same domain to proxy two different hosts?

Tags: nginx, proxy, url-rewriting, webserver, cloudflare

I have a main domain, eg.: **mydomain.com**.
A Single Page Application: **myApp**, hosted on: myApp.somehost.com (IP: {ip.of.myapp}).
A WordPress Site: **myWP**, hosted on: myWP.anotherhost.com (IP: {ip.of.mywp}).

The goal:

1. **mydomain.com** should show **myWP** (this is straight forward, I need an A record in my DNS NameServer, with {ip.of.mywp})
2. **mydomain.com/app** should show **myApp**.

How would you solve the second one? Is there a frontend-proxy service provider or so?

What I tried:

- Cloudflare CDN: rewriting the hostname is not allowed.
- Vercel: here I can host static pages (myApp) and proxy certain subpaths. But not the root url! So **mydomain.com** can't show **myWp**

What should I do? Please help... Thanks

Note: I'm not planning to move **myApp** and **myWP** from their current servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct about rewrite rules not supporting this with Cloudflare, but you can use Cloudflare Workers to act as a proxy. Here is a blog article going over details of one way you could achieve what you are looking for -

https://blog.cloudflare.com/subdomains-vs-subdirectories-improved-seo-part-2/

Here are also a number of other Worker examples that may come in handy -

https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/examples

Do keep in mind the pricing / limits of free plan if you go this route - https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/platform/pricing

Comment: The blog post you linked is the perfect example, thanks!

Comment: @MarcellKiss do you know any ways of achieving this without using cloudflare?